# How to return a list from a list Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to get a list that includes all names of cities from my test data type. Bellow my data is the code I am trying to use that splits the city into string name 52,5 into x and y and the list of numbers. Right now I am struggling with returning a list that consists only of the city names.

```
type City = (String, Int, Int, [Int])

testData :: [City]
testData =
    [
    ("Amsterdam",   52,   5,    [1158, 1149, 1140, 1132]),
    ("Athens",      38,  23 ,   [3153, 3153, 3154, 3156]),
    ("Berlin",      53,  13    [3567, 3562, 3557, 3552]),
    ("Brussels",    51,   4,   [2096, 2081, 2065, 2050]),
    ("Bucharest",   44 , 26,  [1794, 1803, 1812, 1821]),
    ("London",      52,   0,  [9426, 9304, 9177, 9046]),
    ("Madrid",      40,  4,   [6669, 6618, 6559, 6497]),
    ("Paris",       49,  2,  [11079, 11017, 10958, 10901]),
    ("Rome",        42, 13,  [4278, 4257, 4234, 4210]),
    ("Sofia",       43, 23,   [1284, 1281, 1277, 1272]),
    ("Vienna",      48,  16,    [1945, 1930, 1915, 1901]),
    ("Warsaw",      52,  21,    [1790, 1783, 1776, 1768])
    ]

allNames :: [City] -> [String]
allNames((name,x,y,[y0,y1,y2,y3]):rest)= name : allNames(rest)

``
```

Comment: ...and what goes wrong with your attempt that you need help with?

Answer (score 5):

I think you only need

```hs
map (\(a,_,_,_) -> a) testData
```

These are answers to a few questions that could pop up in your mind upon seeing the line above:

- *What is `map`?* [The documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:map) should be sufficient to understand what `map` does.
- [*What are `\` and `->`?*](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function)
- *What is `_`?* It's the *I don't care what this is* wildcard. (Search for *underscore* [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html).)

But most of all, you need to study a bit first. Try with [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters).

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the comma missing in the Berlin entry of your test data you need a recursion anchor to match all patterns in your function:

```
allNames :: [City] -> [String]
allNames [] = []
allNames ((name,_,_,_):rest)= name : allNames rest
```

Output:

```
*Main> allNames testData
["Amsterdam","Athens","Berlin","Brussels","Bucharest","London","Madrid","Paris","Rome","Sofia","Vienna","Warsaw"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with a better type definition:

```
data City = City { name :: String, x :: Int, y ::Int, data :: [Int])
```

Then

```
allNames :: [City] -> [String]
allNames = map name
```

Even without record syntax, you can define the appropriate accessor function yourself. Functions are cheap in Haskell; don't be afraid to define lots of them.

```
data City = City String Int Int [Int]

name :: City -> String
name (City n _ _ _) = n

allNames :: [City] -> [String]
allNames = map name
```